# How do I prove this equality with cardinalities?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, quotient-group

I have the following problem and I am a bit stuck.

Let $G$ be a finite group acting on $X$. We first consider the case that $X=G/H$ where $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. Here we consider the natural action $$G\times G/H \rightarrow G/ H,\,\,(g,xH)\mapsto gxH.$$
We additionally introduce the following quantity $$E=\{(g,k)\in G\times G\mid k^{-1}gk\in H\}.$$
Then we have the following two functions $p_1,p_2:E\rightarrow G$ with $p_1(g,k)=g$ and $p_2(g,k)=k$.
I have just shown that $p_2$ is surjective, that there is a bijection from $p_2^{-1}(k)$ to $kHk^{-1}$ and that $\text{card}(E)=\text{card}(H)\cdot \text{card}(G)$. Now I have also shown that there is a bijection between $p_1^{-1}$ and $F_g=\{k\in G\mid g(kH)=kH\}=\{k\in G\mid kH\in (G/H)^g\}$. I also know that $\text{card}(F_g)=\text{card}((G/H)^g)\cdot \text{card}(H)$. I only need to show that $$\text{card}(E)=\sum_{g\in G} \text{card}((G/H)^g)\cdot \text{card}(H).$$

I somehow don't see the point.
Could someone help me here?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,
$$
\operatorname{card}(E)
= \sum_{g \in G} \operatorname{card}(p_1^{-1}(g))
= \sum_{g \in G} \operatorname{card}(F_g)
= \sum_{g \in G} \operatorname{card}((G / H)^g) \cdot \operatorname{card}(H)
$$
by the work which you have already done. Presumably you did the same thing in order to show that $\operatorname{card}(E) = \operatorname{card}(G) \cdot \operatorname{card}(H)$.

Comment: sorry why did we know the first equality between $card(E)$ and $card(p_1^{-1}(g))$

Comment: Is this because E es the disjoint union of the $p_1^{-1}(g)$'s?

Comment: @Strandkorb That's right; if $f : X \to Y$ is any function between any sets at all then we always have that $X = \bigcup_{y \in Y} f^{-1}(y)$. (And this union is disjoint.) This is basically what it means to be a function; each element $x \in X$ maps to exactly one $y \in Y$.